# How can i search for text in class from html

Tags: python, html, api, bots

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://rocket-league.com/trading?filterItem=4&filterCertification=0&filterPaint=1&filterMinCredits=0&filterMaxCredits=100000&filterPlatform%5B%5D=2&filterSearchType=1&filterItemType=0"

page = urlopen(url)
html_bytes = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_bytes, features="html.parser")
FindT = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "rlg-item__quantity"})
print(FindT)
```

When i run this i will get

```
700 </div>, <div class="rlg-item__quantity --quantity-700 --premium wide">
700 </div>, <div class="rlg-item__quantity --quantity-750 --premium wide">
750 </div>, <div class="rlg-item__quantity --quantity-400 --premium wide">
400 </div>, <div class="rlg-item__quantity --quantity-900 --premium wide">
900 </div>, <div class="rlg-item__quantity --quantity-750 --premium wide">
750 </div>, <div class="rlg-item__quantity --quantity-750 --premium wide">
```

I want to separate the quantity-750 into its own string and i cant find how to do this
If you can help that would be great

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import bs4

result = requests.get('https://rocket-league.com/trading?filterItem=4&filterCertification=0&filterPaint=1&filterMinCredits=0&filterMaxCredits=100000&filterPlatform%5B%5D=2&filterSearchType=1&filterItemType=0')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'lxml')

FindT = soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "rlg-item__quantity --quantity-750 --premium wide"})

for x in FindT:
    print(x.find('p').getText())
```

Basically you have to scrape the particular class and uuse a for loop to get the html tags inside the div, then you can use the .getText() method to get the content inside the tag. I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that? I Also remove the \n - Chars in every div tag-line

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://rocket-league.com/trading?filterItem=4&filterCertification=0&filterPaint=1&filterMinCredits=0&filterMaxCredits=100000&filterPlatform%5B%5D=2&filterSearchType=1&filterItemType=0"

page = urlopen(url)
html_bytes = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_bytes, features="html.parser")
FindT = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "rlg-item__quantity"})
print(FindT)

list_of_rag_item_quality = []
for t in FindT:
    int_t = int(t.string.replace("\n",""))
    list_of_rag_item_quality.append(int_t)
```